# MinGW and std::thread

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mingw, stdthread

So I've been trying to get the following code to compile and run on Windows by using a MinGW compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void test()
{
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(test);
}
```

I'm compiling with the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.exe
```

Now the problem is the version of MinGW one should use and I've tried about all the versions I know of.

1. MinGW-builds: [thread-win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/32-bit/threads-win32/sjlj/)
2. MinGW-builds: [thread-posix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/32-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/)
3. MinGW-w64: [stdthread experimental rubenvb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-experimental-stdthread/)
4. MinGW-w64: [stdthread experimental rubenvb 4.7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-dw2-4.7-experimental-stdthread/)

Number 1 doesn't work, since GCC [apparently only supports](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/76836/#msg412938) pthread stuff internally.

Number 2 does compile and it essentially even outputs `test` (see the last line of the output), but it also crashes with the error:

```
terminate called without an active exception

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
test
```

Number 3 and 4 again do compile, but they don't output `test` and instead instantly crashes, but with a more descriptive output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Google brought me of course to the [GCC bug tracker](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52681) and some other posts, that suggested to use `-pthread`, which doesn't help at all.

I've also tried manually linking against `winpthread` and `pthread`, but that doesn't do anything either.

There's also no difference between `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11`...

I'm really lost right now and don't know, if it's at all possible to get a MinGW version, that supports `std::thread`, but maybe I'm just overlooking some compiler flags. I hope someone out there can help me!

Comment: Hours spent to find a solution, finally point 2 worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot to join your thread:

```
t.join();
```

Comment: Okay I think I'm gonna kill myself now... But why does it has to return such a cryptic error? It still doesn't work with all versions, but at least with one. Thanks!

Comment: Destroying a joinable thread causes an exception to be thrown. Since you're not catching the exception, the program terminates.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, there is already a native win32 implementation of std::thread and sync primitives. It is a header-only library and works on any C++11 compliant version of MinGW.
https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads

Comment: That's not really an answer to the already solved problem, thus a comment would've been better suited. Thanks for sharing though!