# CodeBlocks c++ - Can't use Thread because the compiler doesn't support it

Tags: c++, multithreading, codeblocks

Firstly I wanted to create a program that would count the time from the user input time to zero, this was the code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

//  sleep(5000);
int runTimer = 1;
int seconds;
int hoursLeft;
int minutesLeft;
int secondsCount=0;
void timeLeft ()
{
    hoursLeft = seconds/3600;
    minutesLeft = seconds/60 - hoursLeft*60;
}
void timer ()
{
    while(runTimer=1)
    {
         if (secondsCount == 60)
    {
    timeLeft();
    cout << "The Amount of time left is: " << hoursLeft << " hours and " << minutesLeft << " minutes left." << endl;
    secondsCount=0;
    }
    secondsCount++;
    seconds--;
    Sleep(1000);
    timer();
    }

}
int main()
{
    // introduction and time picking
    cout << "Welcome to my Timer - Please set the amount of hours and than minutes you want the timer to run" << endl;
    double requestedHours, requestedMinutes;
    cin >> requestedHours;
    cin >> requestedMinutes;
    double requestedSeconds = requestedHours*3600 + requestedMinutes*60;
    seconds = requestedSeconds;
    cout << "Timer Started";
    timer();
}
```

But than I wanted to add a function in which the user could type a word or a letter to pause the program, (and after a bit of reearching I found out about threading) - but when I added `#include <thread>` I got this massage -

```
"#error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#endif"
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Your error message is giving you the solution...

Comment: You installed a CodeBlocks that supports an older version of C++.  To upgrade, Google "codeblocks C++ 11".  For example: [StackOverflow: How can I add C++11 support to code::blocks compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler) or [YouTube: How to add C++11 support to code::blocks compiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNLZEhWZ1og)

Comment: @paulsm4 CodeBlocks is not a compiler, and if this message occurs in `libstdc++`, he is using a version of `gcc` that *does* support C++11 since they are shipped together.

Comment: @o11c: I *know* Codeblocks is an IDE (I much prefer Eclipse/CDT, thank you).  The point is, he needs to Google for an update procedure *specific to Codeblocks* . Which may or may not differ from a procedure to update Eclipse, or update MinGW ... or, for that matter, update a command-line gcc/g++ toolchain.

Comment: @paulsm4 Except that absolutely nothing needs to be upgraded. Only a project setting needs to be changed.

Comment: Separate from the thread aspect, your code reads from `int seconds` without initilising it: that's undefined behaviour. And, your condition `while(runTimer=1)` is flawed... you need `==` to do a comparison: as it is you assign `1` to `runTimer` every time through the loop, and `1` (being non-zero) is considered `true`, so the loop keeps executing. Which won't start to matter until you stop your function being recursive: as is, it calls itself and only stops when there's a stack overflow, but that'd take a long time at one call per second, so you're probably Control-Cing out first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using g++ in Windows so I assume it is a flavour of MinGW that came with Code::Blocks.

GNU glibc doesn't support Windows threads (its dev team doesn't care about Windows) so you have to either use a MinGW pthread build, or use an add-on.

Firstly you should add `-std=c++11` to your build options.

However, your error message suggests you have installed quite an old version of g++ so I would recommend upgrading to Mingw-w64  (an actively-maintained fork of Mingw). [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947302/meaning-of-options-in-mingw-w64-installer) for installation help.

For more info about thread support in various versions of MinGW see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718904/mingw-and-stdthread). I use Mingw-w64 with Win32 threads and the meganz addon in Code::Blocks successfully.

Comment: In Code::Blocks, how (in which section of Build Options) should one add ```-std=c++11```?